# Toggle hide on already hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like `#profile-menu` to start as `.hidden` and when the user clicks `.profile-toggle` it should remove or add the `.hidden` class. How can I make this work in jQuery?

Here is what I have tried.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <button class="profile-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile</button>
           <button type="button">Sign up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="side">
    <li id="profile-menu" class="hidden">TOGGLE THIS MATE</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".profile-toggle").click(fucntion() {
    if ($(".side li#profile-menu").is(".hidden")) {
        $(".side li#profile-menu").removeClass("hidden");
        $(".side li#profile-menu").addClass("show");
    }
    else { 
        $(".side li#profile-menu").addClass("hidden");
        $(".side li#profile-menu").removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: You have Typo in `fucntion()`

Comment: <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-bar">
                <button class="profile-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile</button>
                <button type="button">Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: OH DAMN let me check

Comment: nah, that didn't fix it. the trigger is the button that inside a few divs.

Comment: Can you add some more context on what the HTML looks like and where you want to show and hide? Also, since you are using jQuery, why not use jQuery's show() http://api.jquery.com/show/ and hide() http://api.jquery.com/hide/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in `function`(you have `fucntion`), but it can be simplified to

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".profile-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#profile-menu").toggleClass("hidden show")
  });
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="profile-toggle">profile-toggle</button>
<ul class="side">
  <li id="profile-menu" class="hidden">TOGGLE THIS MATE</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why would you use `jQuery(function ()...` if you use `$` everywhere else?

Comment: @royhowie was suppose to use `jQuery(function($) {`

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a function called .toggleClass()

Just use:

```
$(".side li#profile-menu").toggleClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class and add style or define the class as -

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="side">
     <li id="profile-menu" style="display:none;">TOGGLE THIS MATE</li>
</ul>
```

Use `toggle()`.

```
$(".profile-toggle").click(fucntion() {
     $(".side li#profile-menu").toggle();
});
```